# Google Colab with Java (using JShell)

Tags: java, jupyter, google-colaboratory, jshell

I`m trying Java on GoogleColab using JShell.
I could run it, but input fields is not visible(abc -> dot dot dot).
Do you know how to solve it ?

My scripts are;

```
import os       #importing os to set environment variable
def install_java():
  !apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null      #install openjdk
  os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"     #set environment variable
  !java -version       #check java version
  !javac -version
install_java()

#then

!jshell
```

I also used IJava, but same issue occured.

Does anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I made an example of IJava on Colab.

Go to this shortcut

```
bit.ly/colabjava
```

It will redirect you here

https://colab.research.google.com/github/vistec-AI/colab/blob/master/ijava.ipynb

Then

- run the first cell
- reload page
- run the second and other cells.

Comment: Awesome.
How to add java runtime type ??

Comment: Solved this theme.
At first, I run following script to change kernelspec, then, did above instruction.
//import json
//notebook = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/JShellTest.ipynb"
//#load ipynb as json
//json_load = json.load(open('notebook', 'r'))
//# edit kernelspec
// java_kernelspec = {
//       "name": "java",
//       "display_name": "java"
//     }
// json_load["metadata"]["kernelspec"] = java_kernelspec
// savepath = notebook
// with open(savepath, 'w') as outfile:
//     json.dump(json_load, outfile)

//
//restart kernel